# CSS not styling properly - will not work (bizarre)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I don't even know where to start on this one. When I resize below 1600px the site breaks 100% even though it has media queries in place to resize/hide/move elements. But to pinpoint one issue that eludes me, I have a logo in an id that is set to a height of 175px and width to auto. At any browser size it's always a height of 564px. Check out some code below:

```css
img #fpa-logo {
  bottom: -25px;
  height: 175px;
  margin-left: 12.5%;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 nav" id="nav-w-back">
    <div class="col-sm-5 fLeft">
      <a href="http://www.fpacny.com"><img src="../images/FPA-logo-new150-02.png" alt="FPA Logo" id="fpa-logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <ul class="nav fRight" id="nav-ul">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services<span style="font-size: .75em"> &#9660;</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Personalized Care</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Health Care Services</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Links<span style="font-size: .75em"> &#9660;</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Patient Information and Forms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Patient Friendly Sites</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Staff Bios</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you're interested in more code - the test site is: http://fpacny.com/index_test.php where you can play with the sizing etc. At this point you would likely notice that the main image background only resizes properly when an inline HTML style addition of:

```
style="height: auto; width: 100%;"
```

is added. Otherwise, that breaks too.

Why won't my linked CSS override this? I've never had this issue on any website I've developed and it is driving me absolutely nuts!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hjo8pLxe/

Comment: It's not bizzare, you just have a broken Bootstrap HTML structure. Columns belong *within* `.rows` as per the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) `Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows`

Comment: Your CSS suggests you're trying to target something *within* the image it's self.

Comment: Convert your code into a jsFiddle or Codepen so that we can see the problem reproduced.

Comment: You have the charset set twice to different types.

Comment: So if it was: row / col-12 / row / col-5 / col-7 that would be correct? That still breaks the logo and navigation near the top if I had another row after the col-12

Comment: i expanded my answer below, you should definitely learn the basics of the bootstrap grid first before you try to fix this issue. With a correct usage of the grid this error wouldn't happen.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hjo8pLxe/

Comment: I've just looked at your fiddle @JAPytlak It looks broke now matter the width. It's also missing stuff like images etc...

Comment: Everything breaks under 1600px and there's nothing in the css indicating it should do so. It used to break at 1024px, then it started at 1600px without any input on my end. The only way to keep the main background image on the site from *not* breaking is to give it an inline html style, as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write

```css
img#fpa-logo
```

to target the logo.

Edit: Just saw you are using bootstrap 4: Why not use the "img-fluid" class on the image? Then it won't get too big and scale down automatically if the row/column gets smaller.

```
<img class="img-fluid" {...} >
```

Or do you need any special behaviour, other than automatic resizing?

And you should also look more into the column features of bootstrap, you are using a lot of `position: absolute` in your css which is not needed at all for your design and would prevent a lot of errors if you would use bootstrap instead.

Comment: That works above 1600px, but why would it break again on browser resize when media queries tell it to get even smaller?

Comment: I just need it to get smaller on window resize so that it doesn't take up the whole screen and break the navigation. At a smaller size I'll remove the current nav and use a hamburger menu drop-down but wanted to get this situated before getting to the next step. - I've been using absolute positioning to keep elements on top of the top background image rather than moving around - the plan was to remove that on window resize

Comment: bootstrap already has the functionally for replacing the navigation with a burger menu at any breakpoint already built in. You are also not using a background image, you are using a regular image. Try setting your background image as a background image and get rid of all your position absolute. It's definitely not needed. And there is no "easy" or "quick" Fix for that, I'm sorry.

Comment: I've got to strip this thing back and go at it line by line. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Change your ccs to

```html
img#fpa-logo {
  bottom: -25px;
  height: 175px;
  margin-left: 12.5%;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
}
```